# lookup and merge nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate, lookup

I have two collections I want to combine with aggregate. First is 'books'

```
{
    "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d28",
    "title": "Good Omens",
    "author": [
        { 
             "_id": "56e31ce076cdf50ssdksi998j",
             "function": "Writer"
        },
        {
             "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d29",
             "function": "Illustrator"
        }
    ]
}
```

The second one is 'authors'

```
{
    "_id": "56e31ce076cdf50ssdksi998j",
    "name": "Terry Pratchett"
}
{
    "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d29",
    "name": "Neil Gaiman"
}
```

The result I expect is this:

```
{
    "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d28",
    "title": "Good Omens",
    "author": [
        { 
             "_id": "56e31ce076cdf50ssdksi998j",
             "function": "Writer",
             "name": "Terry Pratchett"
        },
        {
             "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d29",
             "function": "Illustrator",
             "name": "Neil Gaiman"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm not able to merge both arrays. The approach I've been trying so far is using an aggregate query with lookup and project but it doesn't combine the arrays.
If I do this:

```
Books.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'authors',
            localField: 'author._id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'authors'
        }
    }
    {
        $project: {
            title: 1,
            'authors._id': 1,
            'authors.name': 1,
            'authors.function': '$author.function'
        } 
    }
])
.exec(...)
```

I get something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d28",
    "title": "Good Omens",
    "author": [
        { 
             "_id": "56e31ce076cdf50ssdksi998j",
             "function": ["Writer", "Illustrator"],
             "name": "Terry Pratchett"
        },
        {
             "_id": "56e31ce076cdf52e541d9d29",
             "function": ["Writer", "Illustrator"],
             "name": "Neil Gaiman"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I don't want to get all data in every author, just the corresponding by position.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

```
Books.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$author"},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"authors",
    "localField":"author._id",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"author.name"
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"author.name":{"$arrayElemAt":["$author.name",0]}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id",
    "title":{"$first":"$title"},
    "author":{"$push":"$author"}
  }}
])
```